# Add a trusted domain to everyone in exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Currently we have an HR email going out to the all of our staff. By default, the email gets sorted into the junk email for everyone.

I'd like to use the PowerShell cmdlet `Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration` to add the sending domain as a `trusted domain` to everyone without having to set it individually for every person.

I know I need to use

```
 Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration DomainGoesHere -TrustedSendersAndDomains @{Add="whatever@abc123.com")
```

However I don't know what I need to add to target everyone in my domain.

Any help so I don't have to change this for hundreds of users by hand.

---

I ran the following command

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -TrustedSendersAndDomains @{Add="mysafedomain.com"}`

and get the following error

> The Junk E-Mail configuration couldn't be set. The user needs to sign in to   Outlook Web App before they can modify their Safe Senders and Recipients or Blocked Senders list.

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (545:Int32) [Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration], DataSourceOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 47A2E998,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.SetMailboxJunkEmailConfiguration
```

---

Here is the code that worked for me, thanks to Booga Roo

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -TrustedSendersAndDomains @{Add="myTrustedDomain.com"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Two options: Have everyone sign into OWA once, or add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the end. I've updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully `Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration` accepts pipeline input for `-Identity`.

This should do it(replace the domain names, of course):

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -TrustedSendersAndDomains @{Add="contoso.com","fabrikam.com"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now with correct placement of the }.

Comment: I can't change it but move the } from the end of the line to after the domains like in my edit. Thanks again for the help Booga Roo

Comment: @Spastek Oops! Thanks for the heads up. The } is now where it should have been!